# Changing value of $scope on ng-click with ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

This is absolutely killing me.

This is where I'm at:

[image]

And when I arrive to this page it prints this into the console:

[image]

Then I click on lorem2 which as a ng-click thats supposed to change the displayed object on the left big square. The curious thing is it posts this into the console, when I click on lorem2:

[image]

It changes the value of that variable but it re writes over that change with the same object that was there in the first place.

And the oddest thing is if I click again I get this:

[image]

Which means now the change stays and it displays lorem2 on the big square.
Any suggestions on what might be triggering this?

This is inside of the controller:

```
$scope.singleArticle = $scope.articlesList[0];
console.log($scope.singleArticle);


$scope.changeArticle = function(article){
    $scope.singleArticle = article;
    console.log($scope.singleArticle);
};
```

That is the function I call on ng click to change the value.

And here you have some relevant html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>{{singleArticle.title}}</p>
            {{singleArticle.content}}
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="article in articlesList | limitTo: (1 - articlesList.length) | limitTo: 3">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a ui-sref="articles_route({ article: article.title})"
               ng-click="changeArticle(article)">{{article.title}}
            </a> {{article.content | limitTo: 100}}.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can you share your template code?

Comment: @JCFord I just edited it. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Why do you have an ng-click on a link which also has a ui-sref? Decide: either you want to execute a function on click, or you want to navigate elsewhere. But you shouldn't do both. Also, the name getArticles is fine for a method which would get several articles. It's terrible, and very confusing, for a variable holding a single article.

Comment: @JBNizet
I'm still learning. Ok I just moved the route into the function and changed the getArticles to getArticle.

Comment: getArticle is still an ugly name for an article. It's a valid name for a method which would get an article. How about "selectedArticle"? Or "displayedArticle"? Or just "article"?

Comment: ok, fair enough, I accept your suggestion, it makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @JBNizet you got any suggestions regarding the original post?

Comment: I already gave my suggestion: don't use ng-click and ui-sref at the same time.

Comment: But even if I use $state.go inside the function instead of using ui-sref in the template, it's still not working. I need to generate a URL with specific params and also to change the singleArticle, that's why I was using both.

Comment: You only posted small fragments of your code, which makes it hard to understand what happens. We have no idea of what your new changeArticle function does, of what the controller does, of how the articles_route route is defined, etc. Post a complete mnimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet There's this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/D6f9Q3fhL294DukEZFOz?p=preview

You can see it is affecting the URL, ie, it's changing as it should, however the article isn't switching on click. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Let me understand what you did. You had trouble getting `$state.go` working inside a function called by ng-click. So instead of fixing that problem or asking us how to fix it, you took the dubious approach of two click handlers on the same element, one click-handler for ng-click and another for the ui-sref directive?

Comment: @georgeawg as shown in the plunker I already have $state.go working inside the function. the problem now is viewing the content when I click. The URL changes, but not the displayed content

Comment: Here's your plunkr, with two additional console.log explaining what you're doing wrong: https://plnkr.co/edit/AzqE3Bak5pQwTZAbxk5f?p=preview

Comment: I see what you're saying by using the stateParams. The problem with it is that I cannot pass the content unless I have it in the URL. In the example you used you were only passing the title and therefore only could use the title

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are loading `article` as a parameter into the `changeArticle` function. `article` is the key of `articlesList` that is being returned by ng-repeat.

You instead need to send the value inside the `articlesList` array that each cycle of ng-repeat is displaying.

Track `ng-repeat` by index with `track by $index` and pass the index of each array item to the function like `articlesList[$index]`

```
    <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>{{singleArticle.title}}</p>
            {{singleArticle.content}}
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="article in articlesList | limitTo: (1 - articlesList.length) track by $index">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a ng-click="changeArticle(articlesList[$index])">{{article.title}}
            </a> {{article.content | limitTo: 100}}.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read about `ng-repat` syntax [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Edit: Also, I'm answering this assuming you got the url path to change like you said in the comments on the OP. This code makes the content change like you requested.